# Drupal 7 file module + php ftp function

Tags: file, drupal, ftp, fopen

I am using the file module to get some files from a form locally and upload to another server. When i try to upload large files it gives me timeout error (i have tried changing php.ini but that's not how i want it to work). That's why I am trying to upload the files via ftp functions. However, i cannot get the source path of the file that i just selected to upload (e.g filepath, not uri). I want to pass this filepath into fopen() function as a source. But i keep getting the error: *ftp_nb_fput() [function.ftp-nb-fput]: Can't open that file: No such file or directory in assets_managed_file_form_upload_submit() (line 303 of FILE_DIRECTORY).*

```
function assets_managed_file_form_upload_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_files']; $i++) {
   if ($form_state['values']['files_fieldset']['managed_field'][$i] != 0) {

  // Make the file permanent.
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['files_fieldset']['managed_field'][$i]);

  $local_path = file_create_url($file->uri);
  //drupal_set_message(t("file->uri: " . $file->uri . "    local path: " . $local_path));

  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  $directory = 'private://cubbyhouse/'. $form_state['values']['allowed_user'];
  file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);


    $source = fopen($local_path,"r");

    $conn = ftp_connect("FTP SERVER") or die("Could not connect");
    ftp_login($conn,"USERNAME", "PASS");
    $ftp_directory = TheDirectoryIwantToPutTheFile . $form_state['values']['allowed_user'];

    $uri_parts = explode("/",$file->uri);
    $filename = $uri_parts[sizeof($uri_parts)-1];
    $target = $ftp_directory . "/" . $filename;
    //drupal_set_message(t($target . " " . $file->uri));
    $ret = ftp_nb_fput($conn,$target,$source,FTP_ASCII);

    while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA)
    {
       // Do whatever you want
       //echo ".";
       // Continue upload...
       $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn);
    }
    ftp_close($conn);


  //$file->uri = file_unmanaged_copy($file->uri, $directory, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
  $file->uid = $form_state['values']['allowed_user'];
  drupal_chmod($file->uri);
  file_save($file);

  // Need to add an entry in the file_usage table.
  file_usage_add($file, 'assets', 'image', 1);

  drupal_set_message(t("Your file has been uploaded!"));
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was mainly because I gave the wrong path as the target. it had to be /public_html/...... instead of /home/our_name/public_html